# C# stopped working properly after break from project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

Two weeks ago, I decided to take a break from my Unity game project, but, when I came back, I was bombarded with errors on code that works just fine.
This screenshot best describes my problem:

[image]

When I hover over "using UnityEngine", it says it's an unnecessary using directive...

Comment: Does it build?  Because you might just need to wait for the database to be built.  The intellisense functions asynchronously to the editor.

Comment: Also Edit-Preferences-External Tools-Regenerate project files.

Comment: @yasirkula you're a freaking god thank you so much :D

Comment: Lesson learned: Unity projects smell breaks, so it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

### I know this problem

and it also happens to me when I take breaks from my code base.
To solve the problem you need to close VS Code and VS and then the Unity Editor as well. Be sure that even their processes are stopped (e.g. through the task manager). Then reopen your Unity Project and wait for all the loading processes to end(you can see that in Unity 2020.x.x in the lower right corner). Then doubleclick a script of yours to open up VS Code or VS. **Important!!** Dont press or type anything yet as the OmniSharp Server and all your extensions have to load in first. When you see the OmniSharp Server running in the lower left corner and it says "Ready", only then you can start coding.

---

Explanation

If VS Code isnt fully loaded and you start coding it doesnt detect all libraries and begins to act as mentioned. Be sure to only start coding when the VS Console says "Ready" in the lower left corner.